# Deserializing JSON string and using in SQL query before returning results to Client Application

Tags: c#, json, wcf, api, rest

I am creating a WCF REST service, whereby I will query a SQL database with the incoming ID's from a Client Application (Currently have a simple Windows Forms App) where I get ID's in a multi-line textbox, serialize them and then send them to the WCF REST service. I use POST due to there not being size restrictions.

From the image, I am at the point of Deserializing the JSON string and this is what I have tried. Basically, I want to achieve the following from here:

Deserialize JSON string > into perhaps a Datatable > Pass DataTable to SQL Query with Table Valued paramater that executes a Stored Procedure on my database (taking the values from datatable in table valued parameter) > This will return a MatterID and MatterBalanceOutstanding for the ID's (in this case ID: G00000013, ID: G00000014, G0000015) which I will then return back from my API to the client application.

I feel I am so close, but just cannot get my head around this. Please can someone help, as I just need to create a DataTable with the ID: G00000013, ID: G00000014, G0000015 as rows.

**Once I have that done, I am fine with the stored procedure part.** Please can someone help?

Here is a screenshot of my code below. Also I will include my code.

[image: Debug of current deserialize]

```
public static MatterDetail DeserializeJSon<MatterDetail>(string jsonString)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MatterDetail));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        MatterDetail obj = (MatterDetail)ser.ReadObject(stream);


        return obj;
    }

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
    public Employee(string first, string last, decimal sal)
    {
        firstname=first;
        lastname=last;
        salary=sal;
    }
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class MatterDetail
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MatterID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal MatterBalanceOutstanding { get; set; }

    public MatterDetail(string ID, decimal M_CurBalanceOutstanding)
    {
        MatterID = ID;
        MatterBalanceOutstanding = M_CurBalanceOutstanding;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Class was specified wrong. MatterDetail should've contained ID instead of MatterID.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class MatterDetailTest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.